# Excel Workbook to html Django/Python

Tags: python, html, django, excel, xlsxwriter

Is there any way to take an excel workbook, and display it on a webpage with the same formatting as the workbook? Im wondering if there is a way to take an excel workbook and paste the contents on a webpage. Basically im looking for something to screenshot the excel document and paste in in my webpage... Is there any way to do this??? (Maybe something similar to Zoho Viewer: https://sheet.zoho.com/sheet/excelviewer)

**Current Wepbage:**
[image]

**After Adding the Excel Workbook**
[image]

NOTE: I am using xlsxwriter to populate the excel sheet.

Comment: what's your office version? depending you can take a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-it-Embed-an-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-OneDrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081)

Answer (score 1):

should the xl file reside in your local machine? or are you open to storing it in the cloud ? Since you mentioned zoho viewer you might want to check out zoho office APIs [here](https://www.zoho.com/docs/help/office-apis.html) using which you can use the API to  upload a file and get back a link with the file rendered in a xl viewer which you can paste into an iFrame etc to display it on your page.

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to get around doing what you're referring to.  Would you be open to using Google Sheets or do it have to be MS Excel?  If so, I'd say use google drive and Google Sync.  This way, you can make your excel on your local machine, save it.  Create a python script that copies the file from the saved location, to the google drive on your machine.  Then google drive will update/sync it.  Then it's just a matter of logging into google and copying the file link, then you can use that link so long as you don't change any names of the file.  I used this as a solution at one of my previous jobs because google is free and available 24/7.  I hoped that helps...

Comment: This is helpful, but not exactly what I am looking for. The way the excel workbook is generated is through a django management command. Currently, it saves it to a temporary file and emails that file. In the end I want everything to be completely automatic. So that when I run the managment command, it will still send out the email containing the excel file, but also auto update the most recent file that was created via the management command.

Comment: Are you hosting everything yourself  Do you have access to apache/IIS wwwroot?  Are you using an SMTP Relay to send emails?  Or are you using a free/paid online host provider for your program?